# pdf generation from dwr json data

Tags: jqgrid, pdf-generation, export-to-pdf

I call a method using dwr, where i l load a grid. That grid data must be generated in the form of a pdf.

```
LogsDataHandler.fetchEmailList(id1, id2, date1, date2,function(data){

}
```

the return data must be generated as a pdf. Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to export jqgrid to excel built: http://www.trirand.net/documentation/php/_32h0wojvn.htm

stackoverflow answer:
[JQGrid: Export Grid to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348335/jqgrid-export-grid-to-pdf)

examples:
http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/export/pdf/default.php
http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/export-to-excel-and-pdf/

Comment: I do not think so. It is worth a try. I tried the first link and I have downloaded PDF file.

Comment: Plesz did you try with jsp jqgrid ? Inside the onclick function instead of "url" : "querygrid.php" what should i give ?

Comment: No, i opened the following link: http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/export/pdf/default.php, clicked the print icon and PDF files are saved. The more I think of the example source code visible.