# Adding Comment to a cell in a spreadsheet document created using OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml, xlsx

I am creating an xlsx file using openXML. I want to add comments to some row cells. Is there any way to add comments to the cell. Or should I use Microsoft.Office.Interop to add comments to the excel cells ?

Comment: Not sure if this will work in current versins but see if this heps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494856/how-to-add-a-comment-to-a-cell-in-excel-2007-using-the-open-xml-sdk-2-0

Comment: [This tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) can help when documentation is hard to find. It takes an existing spreadsheet and generates the code that would generate that spreadsheet. You would add a comment to a spreadsheet, run it through the tool, and see what code it generated. It's a little like recording a VBA macro and looking at it to see which properties and methods to call. (I've never, ever done that.) Interop is bad for living things.

Answer (score 1):

I used the [Open XML SDK Productivity Tool for Microsoft Office](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) which lets you load an Excel or Word file and then emits the C# code to produce that exact file.

Then I created a file with a comment. First I tried with two comments but the amount of code it generates makes it hard to tell what's what.

The result is not pretty to look at. You could reduce a lot of it and probably eliminate some. But it's a way to find out what's going on under the hood.

You can also skip all of this and just use [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Adding-a-comment), which after looking at what comes next you can imagine why someone felt the need to make this easier.

The key steps are:

- Create a new `Comments`
- Create a new `CommentsList` (?!!!)
- Create a new `Comment` which has a `Reference` property indicating which cell it belongs to
- Create a new `CommentText`
- Create a new `Run`
- Append the `Run` to the `CommentText`
- Append the `CommentText` to the `Comment`
- Append the `Comment` to the `CommentsList`
- Append the `CommentsList` to the `Comments`
- Set the `WorksheetCommentsPart.Comments` property to the `Comments`.

  ```
  private void GenerateWorksheetCommentsPart1Content(WorksheetCommentsPart worksheetCommentsPart1)
  {
      Comments comments1 = new Comments(){ MCAttributes = new MarkupCompatibilityAttributes(){ Ignorable = "xr" }  };
      comments1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("mc", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006");
      comments1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("xr", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision");

      Authors authors1 = new Authors();
      Author author1 = new Author();
      author1.Text = "Hannen, Scott";

      authors1.Append(author1);

      CommentList commentList1 = new CommentList();

      Comment comment1 = new Comment(){ Reference = "B3", AuthorId = (UInt32Value)0U, ShapeId = (UInt32Value)0U };
      comment1.SetAttribute(new OpenXmlAttribute("xr", "uid", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision", "{811649EF-4CB5-4311-BE14-228133003BE4}"));

      CommentText commentText1 = new CommentText();

      Run run1 = new Run();

      RunProperties runProperties1 = new RunProperties();
      FontSize fontSize3 = new FontSize(){ Val = 9D };
      Color color3 = new Color(){ Indexed = (UInt32Value)81U };
      RunFont runFont1 = new RunFont(){ Val = "Tahoma" };
      RunPropertyCharSet runPropertyCharSet1 = new RunPropertyCharSet(){ Val = 1 };

      runProperties1.Append(fontSize3);
      runProperties1.Append(color3);
      runProperties1.Append(runFont1);
      runProperties1.Append(runPropertyCharSet1);
      Text text1 = new Text(){ Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve };
      text1.Text = "This is my comment!\nThis is line 2!\n";

      run1.Append(runProperties1);
      run1.Append(text1);

      commentText1.Append(run1);

      comment1.Append(commentText1);

      commentList1.Append(comment1);

      comments1.Append(authors1);
      comments1.Append(commentList1);

      worksheetCommentsPart1.Comments = comments1;
  }
  ```

Comment: Actually the question @EdneyHolder linked to says pretty much the same thing and offers some suggestions to make all of this more manageable.

Comment: I could not generate the comments with the above code. Is there any other working example like just to understand how the comments can be put using openxml. The  link given by @EdneyHolder when I tried I get excel error and no success in putting the comments.

Comment: Finally got an working example [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b4624455-8c4d-46c9-b020-6162e5bf55ba/how-to-add-comments-for-cell?forum=oxmlsdk) where we can put a single comment at least and  for more comments we will need the cell row id and column id. The same can be followed in the link commented above by @EdneyHolder. Thank you guys for your quick help.

Comment: @ScottHannen Please let me know how to add this worksheetcommentsPart to worksheetpart which already created .I tried to sheet and its not showing

Comment: @Shubhamkumar Could you please share working example link to start with as earlier one is not available anymore